# Site load without css after Migrating from one server to another

Tags: magento2, css, permissions, file-permissions

After migrating my magento site from one server to another, I encounter the following problem: the site loads, but without styles (css), it is as if it could not access the file.

here are the permissions I have on my files:
[image: The permission of my flies]

Comment: Did you make sure to rebuild/recompile after the move?

Comment: @joeybab3 you mean php bin/magento setup:di:compiler ?

Comment: yes, I believe there may be a few other commands needed to regenerate it as well

Comment: @joeybab3 when i try this it shows me a PHP fatal error

Comment: what is the error? That may be why it's not showing CSS as it never finishes compiling

Comment: Now the site don't display and show this error!

Comment: can you please add frontend of your site?

Comment: Yes I added the error it show when i try to load it in a comment below

Answer (score 0):

@joeybab3 this error pop when i try to compile

[image: error when i setup:di:compile]

Comment: Seems like you didn't install an extension or module that is required?

Answer (score 0):

@joeybab3 now i have this error when i try to acces to the website

`ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does not exist in /var/www/www.soluclef.com/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:26 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/www.soluclef.com/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(26): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\\Framewo...') #1 /var/www/www.soluclef.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(54): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\\Framewo...') #2 /var/www/www.soluclef.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\\Framewo...') #3 /var/www/www.soluclef.com/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #4 /var/www/www.soluclef.com/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(235): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array) #5 /var/www/www.soluclef.com/index.php(38): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\\Framewo...') #6 {main}`

Comment: @User 69 just here

Comment: Please use the comments to tag me, I won't get notified if you post responses as an answer to your question

Comment: This error often can happen when you were unable to bin/magento setup:di:compile.